# How can I move the picture on my html page?

Tags: html

I have a picture and I need to move it under the word with a dash, but I can't do it

for some reason he does not want to raise this icon and now I add others and he puts them even lower

code:

```
<a href="https://vk.com/feed"><img src="vk.png" 
    height="70" width="70" style="margin-left: 1130px; margin-top: 0px;" ></a>
```

[image]

all code :

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ответы на ОГЭ,ЕГЭ,ВПР,ОЛИМПИАДЫ</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body {
            background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }           
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">

  <a href="file:///C:/Users/Леонид/Desktop/сайт/index.html">
    <img src="name.png" height="175" width="290" style="margin-left:80px; margin-top:10px;">
  </a>

  <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: right; width: 87%;">Подпишись</h1> 

  <img src="line.png" height="180" width="260" style="margin-left:750px; margin-top:7px;">

  <a href="https://vk.com/otvet2020ru">
    <img src="vk.png" height="70" width="70" style="margin-left:1130px; margin-top:0px;">
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only should move the `<a>` tag into `<h1>` tag, then `margin-left:1130px; margin-top:0px;` are no longer necessaries

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Ответы на ОГЭ,ЕГЭ,ВПР,ОЛИМПИАДЫ</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png" />
    <style>
        body {
            background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }           
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-attachment:fixed" topmargin="0">

  <h1 style="position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: right; width: 87%;line-height: 40px;border: 1px solid blue;">  
      <a href="https://vk.com/otvet2020ru" style="display: -moz-grid-group;border: 2px solid red;">
         <img src="vk.png" width="70" height="70"></a>Подпишись
  </h1> 

  <img src="line.png" style="margin-left:750px; margin-top:7px;" width="260" height="180">

</body>
</html>
```

In order to help you faster should link the images to a internet url, so you and we can use code snippet tool here.